# Trouble using join on SQL with 3 tables

Tags: sql, select, join

I have these 3 queries

```
select tab_ug.cod 
  from tab_ug

select coalesce(sum(valor),0)
  from contas
 where contas.conta_monitorada = 'Sim'
group by ug

select coalesce(sum(valor_justificativa),0)
  from contas, justificativas
 where contas.cod = justificativas.cod_contas
   and contas.conta_monitorada = 'Sim'
group by ug
```

I would like to join them into a single query, but I'm having troubles doing that...
Could someone help?
The table "**tab_ug**" connects to the "**contas**" table by `contas.ug = tab_ug.cod`.
The table "**justificativas**" connects to the "**contas**" table by `contas.cod = justificativas.cod_contas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  t.cod,
        coalesce(sum(c.valor), 0) As [ValorSum],
        coalesce(sum(j.valor_justificativa), 0) As [ValorJustSum]
from tag_ug t
inner join contas c On c.ug = t.cod
inner join justificativas j On j.cod_contas = c.cod
where c.conta_monitorada = 'Sim'
group by t.cod,
        c.ug
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: That usually means you have an extra comma after your very last field you specify in your select statement....is there one there?

Comment: I see no commas in the wrong place, I used the exact same code as you posted (except for the tag_ug which is tab_ug :P)

Comment: It was the [] who was blocking the query, I used "" instead and it worked, but it isn't exactly what I wanted, it's returning the same result as the select from Fabien TheSolution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way :

```
select contas.ug, coalesce(sum(valor),0), coalesce(sum(valor_justificativa),0)
  from tab_ug, contas, justificativas
 where contas.conta_monitorada = 'Sim'
   and contas.ug = tab_ug.cod
   and contas.cod = justificativas.cod_contas
 group by contas.ug
```

Comment: that's not what I want, the where clauses cant be together, it filters the query more than it should where it shouldnt... I need to use a full join, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

First pass (with table aliases, to make it a bit more legible):

```
SELECT
   t1.cod
  ,coalesce(sum(t2.valor), 0)  FirstSum
  ,coalesce(sum(t3.valor_justificativa), 0)  SecondSum
 from tab_ug t1
  inner join contas t2
   on co.ug = t1.cod
  inner join justificativas t3
   on t3.cod_contas = t2.cod
 where t2.conta_monitorada = 'Sim'
 group by t1.cod
```

(Always use the `ON` clause when joining tables)

This query assumes that you only want to retrieve items that are present in all tables. If a given item in `tab_ug` is not found in `contas`, it will not be included in the
result set. Similarly, if a given item "found" in `contas` is not found in `justificativas`, it will not be factored into the result set.  To work
around this, you'd need to use outer joins, like so:

```
SELECT
   t1.cod
  ,coalesce(sum(t2.valor), 0)  FirstSum
  ,coalesce(sum(t3.valor_justificativa), 0)  SecondSum
 from tab_ug t1
  left outer join contas t2
   on co.ug = t1.cod
    and t2.conta_monitorada = 'Sim'
  left outer join justificativas t3
   on t3.cod_contas = t2.cod
 group by t1.cod
```

(Outer joins are very hard to get working correctly without the `ON` clause...)

This will include all items in `tab_ug` even if they have no matches in `contas`; similarly, all items in `contas` will be factored in, even if they have
no items in `justificativas`.

There's a more subtle problem here: if a given `contas` items has two or more related rows in `justificativas`, that `contas` item will be factored 
into the sum multiple times, e.g.

```
ug   contas   justificativas
1     A, 1         j7, 102
1     A, 1         j8, 103
2     <null>       <null>
```

The group by will take this and produce

```
cod  FirstSum   SecondSum
1       2           205
2       0             0
```

At which point I have to give up, as I don't know the full scope of the query's requirements.